# Getting components to refresh with dynamic property changes

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, geolocation, google-places-api

I'm writing an app that uses a mix of the Geolocation API as well as user-inputted locations and is built using ReactJS.

The app has both a map view pane and a list view pane; the container of both of these (the "parent" or "owner" in React terminology) is what sets the Geolocation.

So, something like this is the container:

```
var App = React.createClass({
/**
Internal callback used by Geolocation API
**/
setPosition: function(position){
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    this.setState({location: {lat:lat, lng:longitude}});        
},
getInitialState: function(){
    return {location: null, statusText: 'Finding you...'}
},
componentDidMount: function(){
/* First use current position on first load */
    if (!navigator.geolocation){
        this.setState({statusText: 'No Geolocation!'});
    }
    else{
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition, this.errorPosition);
    }
},
render: function(){
    return(
            <SearchLocator biasLocation={this.state.location} 
                           statusProp={this.state.statusText} />
    )


}
)};
```

The "SearchLocator" component does a Google Places search. And in turn contains the map pane and the list pane:

```
var SearchLocator = React.createClass({
render: function(){
 return(<div>
    <GeoSuggest onSuggestSelect={this.handleSuggestion} />
    <MapAndListContainer locationProp={this.state.location} />
 </div>)
};
)};
```

And finally, "MapAndListContainer" passes the location prop down to the map pane and the list pane. So, as you can see, location properties in the form of an object that looks like

```
{location: {lat: latValue, lng: lngValue}}
```

is used in setState as well as passed as properties to the children.

Question: I'm only getting the "initial state" props working -- that is, whatever the default initial state is in the app container (topmost parent). But when the location changes, the changes are not propagated throughout the children. Should I use:
1. componentShouldUpdate ?
2. "keys" on the properties?
3. forceUpdate?
4. Something else I've overlooked?

I'm a React Newbie and would love any and all pointers!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of those 4 things. I expect there's some issue with your code somewhere. You seem to be setting lots of props on the SearchLocator element without actually using then. Also have you tried debugging each element's state using the react developer tools? Can you tell me what each element's state/props are after the app starts running?

Comment: @Miguel : first, here's an indicative gist: https://gist.github.com/nonystack/f2587f6a834d12ac39d4 The props set on SearchLocator are used by SearchLocator's children, which are the "Google Places" suggest text area and the actual map. This is all triggered by latitude and longitude. Immediately after the app starts running, the default lat and lng are dummy ones since passing null props is a problem. But later the App reflects geolocation API updates. The children don't.

Answer (score 0):

Please try if this can solve your problem:

```
<MapAndListContainer locationProp={this.props.biasLocation} />
```

Pass `this.props.biasLocation` instead of `this.state.location` to the child `MapAndListContainer`.

Comment: the problem here is that SearchLocator has to maintain a state of its location, and that whatever props are passed to the child of SearchLocator has to reflect a change in state. It was a good guess, but it doesn't solve my problem.